# Why does QVBoxLayout inherit background of my main window? - Python using Qt5 Designer

Tags: css, xml, pyqt5, qt-designer

For some reason, I can see a different result in the Qt designer and the preview windows. I am using Qt Designer v5.15.2, and I couldn't find anything about this problem. Here is a screenshot as well:
[image: screenshot]

The issue is that the vertical layout inherits the gradient background of my main window. Please see *MainWindow - [Preview]* (bottom window).

What I would like to achieve is what I can see in my *MainWindow* (top window). I don't want the vertical layout to have any background at all. Unfortunately, the vertical layout doesn't have a `styleSheet` property, so there is nothing to edit.

I tried to edit the background of the `QLabel` widgets, but it didn't work out well as it had no impact on the background of the vertical layout itself.

Here is the code of my simple GUI in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>471</width>
    <height>261</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>471</width>
    <height>261</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>471</width>
    <height>261</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.216, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));</string>
  </property>
  <property name="iconSize">
   <size>
    <width>25</width>
    <height>25</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>31</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Tier03">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: none;
color: white;
font-size: 10px;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>$2 000</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Tier02">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: none;
color: white;
font-size: 10px;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>$1 000</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Tier01">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: none;
color: white;
font-size: 10px;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>$500</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Try changing the main window stylesheet to `QWidget#centralwidget { background-color: qlineargradient... }`.

Comment: Also, Designer sometimes is a bit inconsistent in what it shows and in the preview. Always try to actually run the program using the created UI to see the *actual* final result.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your suggestion. Even after compiling the UI, the result looks exactly the same as in the preview. I removed the `MainWindow`'s stylesheet and pasted it to the `centralWidget`, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The point is that you should not use generic properties for container widgets, but [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (in this sense, moving the stylesheet to the central widget wouldn't change, as long as you *did* use the selector). Please provide the generated pyuic code with the aforementioned change.

Comment: @musicamante I removed all the individual object stylings and added everything to the main window's stylesheet. This way your very first suggestion worked perfectly! If you posted it as an answer, then I would be able to accept it.